# Golang keep installation status for multiple installations process

Tags: beginner, go, installer

Im fairly **new to Golang** and I appreciate any feedback about how to make the code cleaner.

The code is called by `go-routine` and should update status (fail/success etc) of several installation process.

```
package avss

import (
    "context"
    "sync"

    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/release"

    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"

    avmv1alpha1 "github.vmp/avs/api/v1alpha1"
)

func GetUpdateStatus(ctx context.Context, log logr.Logger, cr client.Object, status *avmv1alpha1.ComponentStatusWithAggregation, statusClient client.StatusClient) func(chartStatus *avmv1alpha1.InstallStatus) error {
    var conditionMutex sync.Mutex

    return func(chartStatus *avmv1alpha1.InstallStatus) error {

        // prevent status update by subroutines at the same time, lock the access to prevent concurrent modification
        conditionMutex.Lock()
        defer conditionMutex.Unlock()
        status.ChartStatus = updateStatus(chartStatus, status.ChartStatus)
        status.Status = overallStatus(status.ChartStatus)
        err := statusClient.Status().Update(ctx, cr)
        return err
    }
}

func overallStatus(chartsStatus []avmv1alpha1.InstallStatus) string {
    overallStatus := ""
    for _, status := range chartsStatus {
        switch status.ReleaseStatus {
        case release.StatusFailed.String():
            overallStatus = "error"
        case release.StatusDeployed.String():
            if overallStatus == "" {
                overallStatus = "installed"
            }
        default:
            if overallStatus != release.StatusFailed.String() {
                overallStatus = "reconcile"
            }
        }
    }
    return overallStatus
}

func updateStatus(newStatus *avmv1alpha1.ChartStatus, cStatus []avmv1alpha1.InstallStatus) []avmv1alpha1.ChartStatus {
    found := false
    for i, status := range cStatus {
        if status.Name == newStatus.Name {
            found = true
            cStatus[i] = *newStatus
        }
    }
    if !found {
        cStatus = append(cStatus, *newStatus)
    }
    return cStatus
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9C8xGV2116O

*The code is working*! however, I guess it can be ***improved*** as this is my first Go program which should be ***run in production*** :-)

If the code is perfect,   please let me know

Comment: I think it is proper.. changes that could be made are ("installed" or "reconcile" -> if this value is being used elsewhere I would suggest you define them as constants in a common go file like params.go)

Answer (score 2):

Overall this looks like a pretty sensible file. Some minor points you might want to consider follow.

#### Imports

`logr` is not imported in the file. I presume this is https://github.com/go-logr/logr. It's passed into the first function but not used. Perhaps remove it from the signature?

#### Discrete strings

`overallStatus` returns one of four strings. You could define these strings as constants [like Siva mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260654/golang-keep-installation-status-for-multiple-installations-process#comment515019_260654). A step further is to introduce a type that groups these strings together. This

- ensures the function returns one of the strings defined, and
- makes it clear what strings can be returned from the function by looking at the signature.

```golang
type status string

const (
    statusUnknown   status = ""
    statusError     status = "error"
    statusInstalled status = "installed"
    statusReconcile status = "reconcile"
)
```